# Local volatile variable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, parallel-processing

In my C# program, I have got method code:

```
Object model;
int score;
for()
{
    int tempScore=0;
    Object tempModel=getModel();
    //some interesting stuff modifying value of tempScore
    if(tempScore>score)
    {
        score=tempScore;
        model=tempModel;
    }
}
```

I would like to use Parallel for insted of normal, but I'm afraid that i will encounter some synchronization issues. I know that I can use lock(model), but what can I do about simple type score? 
model and score are method local variables, therefore they are shared between threads.

Comment: The snippet isn't clear enough.  Consider thread-local variables.  The essential how-to article is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx

Comment: We need to know which variables are shared between threads. We can guess that `score` is shared. You can use thread local scores in a map/reduce algorithm. Or you could use interlocked operations. Or locking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `lock (model)`, it doesn't mean that other threads won't be able to access `model`. What it means is that two threads won't be able to execute a section protected by `lock (model)` at the same time. Because of this, you could use something like `lock (model)` to protect access to `score` too.

**But** that wouldn't work in this case. `lock` doesn't lock on a variable, it locks on an object and you modify which object `model` refers to in the loop. Because of that, I thin the best option here is to create another object and lock on that:

```
object model;
int score;
object modelLock = new object();

Parallel.For(…, (…) =>
{
    int tempScore=0;
    Object tempModel=getModel();
    //some interesting stuff modifying value of tempScore
    lock (modelLock)
    {
        if(tempScore > score)
        {
            score=tempScore;
            model=tempModel;
        }
    }
});
```

If you find out that this is too slow for your needs (because using `lock` does have some overhead, which might be significant for you), you should consider using something like [`Thread.VolatileRead()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread) or [`Interlocked.CompareExchange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange). But be very careful with them, because it's very easy to make your code subtly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! Looks like VolatileRead was exactly what I was looking for, and it works!